# Robotium Solo.waitForFragmentByTag Child Fragments

Tags: android-fragments, robotium

I am pretty sure the answer to this question is no, but I have not found any confirmation of that so here it goes.  Does Robotium Solo.waitForFragmentByTag support child fragments?

Answer (score 0):

Well, according to source code, no, it doesn't support child fragments, because it uses only `fragmentActivity.getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Seems that the only option to assert child fragment is to get it from current fragment with `getChildFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag(..)`.